# Java ConcurrentHashMap Get and Put Atomically

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a ConcurrentHashMap and i want to guarantee that the .get and .put operations are Atomic.

From what i have analyzed, compute is not an option for me here, because i have to do some important stuff in the else block.
Any idea how can i achieve that?

Here is the code - let me know if you need more info

```
private Map<String, Long> ids = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ids.putIfAbsent(mapKey, 0L);
Long newId = generateId(mapKey);
if (newId > ids.get(mapKey)) {
   ids.put(mapKey, newId);
   return newId;
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: Why does "important stuff in the else block" make `compute` not an option?  What is `lastEmittedNodeIds`?

Comment: Are you expecting 'do something else' to be atomic?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which operations need to occur atomically? It might help to use `synchronized` blocks in your code around the atomic action(s), just to make this clear, then ask how you can get rid of them safely.

Comment: my bad @LouisWasserman lastEmittedNodeIds should be ids. Compute would not be an option because i need to have this custom logic in else

Comment: @AleksandarT That doesn't answer the question.  If `compute` could tell you whether or not you _should_ run the `else`, would that suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the Map with an [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html): the Map for getting an AtomicLong per mapKey, and then `compareAndSet` on the AtomicLong for the atomicity you need.

```
private Map<String, AtomicLong> ids = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ids.putIfAbsent(mapKey, new AtomicLong());
AtomicLong idForKey = ids.get(mapKey);
// Optionally, those two lines can be shorted to:
//   ids.computeIfAbsent(mapKey, k -> new AtomicLong())

long newId = generateId(mapKey);
long origId = idForKey.get();
if (newId > origId && idForKey.compareAndSet(origId, newId)) {
   return newId;
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

This will ensure that you only return newId if you were able to install a strictly-increasing id. If someone else got in before you (and specifically, between the `idForKey.get()` and the `compareAndSet`), then you'll still generate `newId`, but you won't use update the AtomicLong, and you'll get to the `// do something else` block.

Comment: Nearly works, but if the value changes betwixt `get` and `compareAndSet` but not to a value as large as `newId`, it'll be wrong. You want something like `for (;;) { long origId = idForKey.get(); if (!(newId > origId)) { break; } if (idForKey.compareAndSet(origId, newId)) { return new Id; } } // do something else`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Thanks a lot! Basically i did not want to use synchronized in this use case.

Comment: Happy it worked! Make sure to take Tom Hawtin's advice -- it's a good catch on a bug in my code!